# Explain this code to compute $\log(1+x)$

Tags: numerical-methods, computer-science, logarithms, floating-point

It's well known that you need to take care when writing a function to compute $\log(1+x)$ when $x$ is small. Because of floating point roundoff, $1+x$ may have less precision than $x$, which can translate to large relative error in computing $\log(1+x)$. In numerical libraries you often see a function `log1p()`, which computes the log of one plus its argument, for this reason.

However, I was recently puzzled by this implementation of `log1p` ([commented source](https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/html/Math_8hpp_source.html#l00288)):

```
def log1p(x):
    y = 1 + x
    z = y - 1
    if z == 0:
        return x
    else:
        return x * (log(y) / z)
```

Why is `x * (log(y) / z)` a better approximation to $\log(1+x)$ than simply `log(y)`?

Comment: Where did you find this implementation, was it from a library that's built into a language or from another source?

Comment: they are same because  from first line $x=y-1$ and this multiplied by $(log(1+x))$/(y-1) is just log(1+x),i think  division helps us to minimize round-off errors or something like this

Comment: @data With floating point arithmetic, after doing `y=1+x` and `z=y-1` you do not necessarily have `z == x`, because of round-off error.

Comment: @Ratz It's on line 224 [here](http://geographiclib.sourceforge.net/html/Math_8hpp_source.html#l00224). I translated from C++ to Python.

Comment: This is a nice example where an aggressive optimizer shouldn't be allowed to replace `x * (log(y) / z)` with `log(1+x)`!

Comment: @ChrisTaylor: The comments say 'y = 1 + z, exactly'. I presume this means if z is 'small' enough so 1?

Comment: @copper.hat No, it holds for all *z*. We have *y=1+z* and *y=1+x* (where the + there is floating point addition) but we don't necessarily have *z=x*.

Comment: What if $1$ is not in the range of the mantissa of $x$ (eg, if $x$ cannot be represented in normalized form, admittedly not a big issue for numbers that large). If $z$ is very small, then $1+z =_f 1$, if $z$ is very large, then $1+z =_f z$ (where $=_f$ means fp equality in some sense).

Comment: For example, in my version of python, both $(1+1^{-16})-1$ and $(1^{+16}+1)-1^{+16}$ are zero (exactly).

Comment: Of course, I meant $10^{\pm 16}$ not $1^{\pm 16}$.

Comment: I doubt this is a better idea than using a hardware $\log(x+1)$ instruction (on platforms that provide it, such as x86).

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/172190) is a related question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer involves a subtlety of floating point numbers. I'll use decimal floating point in this answer, but it applies equally well to binary floating point.

Consider decimal floating point arithmetic with four places of precision, and let

$$x = 0.0001234$$

Then under floating point addition $\oplus$, we have

$$y = 1 \oplus x = 1.0001$$
and
$$z = y \ominus 1 = 0.0001000$$

If we now denote the lost precision in $x$ by $s = 0.0000234$, and the remaining part by $\bar{x}$, then we can write

$$x = \bar{x} + s$$
$$y = 1 + \bar{x}$$
$$z = \bar{x}$$

Now, the exact value of $\log(1+x)$ is

$$\log(1+x) = \log(1+\bar{x}+s) = \bar{x}+s + O(\bar{x}^2) = 0.0001234$$

If we compute $\log(y)$ then we get

$$\log(1+\bar{x}) = \bar{x} + O(\bar{x}^2) = .0001000$$

On the other hand, if we compute $x \times (\log(y)/z)$ then we get

$$(\bar{x}+s) \otimes (\log(1+ \bar{x}) \div \bar{x}) = (\bar{x}+s)(\bar{x}\div \bar{x}) = \bar{x}+s = 0.0001234$$

so we keep the digits of precision that would have been lost without this correction.

Comment: For a brief moment I was contemplating the wrong notion that simply returning $x$ in the `else` block would suffice, until I reminded myself that the `else` block has to work *not only* for $x$ that is small.